# CSS: применить стили ко всем элементам, кроме первого и последнего

Tags: css

Здравствуйте, товарищи!

Каким образом можно применить стили ко всем элементам, кроме первого и последнего?

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">...</div> <!-- первый элемент — margin: 0; -->
    <div class="item">...</div> <!-- стандартный элемент — margin: 10px 0; -->
    <div class="item">...</div> <!-- стандартный элемент — margin: 10px 0; -->
    <div class="item">...</div> <!-- последний элемент — margin: 0; -->
</div>
```

Вот так не работает:

```
.content > .item:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

так тоже:

```
.item:first-child,
.item:last-child {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Всё работает. Просто у вас где-то ещё это перекрывается

```css
.content > .item:not(:last-child):not(:first-child) {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="item">...</div> <!-- первый элемент — margin: 0; -->
    <div class="item">...</div> <!-- стандартный элемент — margin: 10px 0; -->
    <div class="item">...</div> <!-- стандартный элемент — margin: 10px 0; -->
    <div class="item">...</div> <!-- последний элемент — margin: 0; -->
</div>
```

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду, что, перед классами item находится ещё какой-либо элемент?

Comment: @Linne я имею в виду, что у вас где-то подключены ещё CSS стили (может быть даже в том же файле ещё ниже, чем текущие строки) и они перекрывают текущие. Смотрите в консоль и инспектируйте элементы во вкладках Styles и Computed  https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYbUK.png

Comment: Сейчас всё проверил и как выяснилось нет, не подключены. Сам не пойму в чём дело…

Comment: @Linne, чтобы выяснить причину, нужно чтобы код из вопроса воспроизводил проблему, сейчас она не воспроизодится

Answer (score 0):

Вот так работает:

```
.content > .item:not(:last-of-type):not(:first-of-type) {
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    background: red;
}
```